# Reload express server before some mocha tests E66+

Tags: javascript, express, chai

I am building some API endpoints using node/Express and have some problems testing the endpoints.

The problem is that the server needs to be restarted (to clear data stored in memory) between tests.

What is the proper way to restart the Express server amid tests or split the tests to multiple instances?

currently, the following does not work:

```
it('Admin can login', () => {
      chai
        .request(server)
        .post(`${ROOT_URL}/auth/login`)
        .send({
          username: 'admin',
          password: 'admin'
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
          console.log(res);
          expect(res.status).eq(200);
        });
    });

       // need to kill and resart server here

  it('Registered user can login', () => {
  chai
    .request(server)
    .post(`${ROOT_URL}/auth/login`)
    .send(newUser)
    .end((err, res) => {
      expect(res.status).eq(200);
      expect(res.body.message).eq(
        `successful login as ${newUser.username}`
      );
    });
});
```